# Spring Batch restart

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch. I have some question about restart. I know restart feature enabled by default. Any extra code I need to do restart any job? Which jobs are restart-able. How can I test my batch app is restartable. I tried to stop the batch middle of process and run again. It always executing a new job.

Below are my code :

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("dataTransferJob")
    public Job dataJob() {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("data-transfer-job")
                .listener(jobExecutionListener())
                .flow(step()).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("data-transfer-step")
                .<TestData, TestDataVO>chunk(100)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(process())
                .writer(writer)
                .taskExecutor(threadPool)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .listener(stepExecutionListener())
                .listener(chunkListener())
                .throttleLimit(10)
                .build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public ItemReader<TestData> reader() {
        JpaPagingItemReader<TestData> itemReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
        try {
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA";
            JpaNativeQueryProvider<TestData> queryProvider = new JpaNativeQueryProvider<TestData>();
            queryProvider.setSqlQuery(sqlQuery);
            queryProvider.setEntityClass(TestData.class);
            queryProvider.afterPropertiesSet();

            itemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(em.getEntityManagerFactory());

            itemReader.setPageSize(100);
            itemReader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);
            itemReader.afterPropertiesSet();
            itemReader.setSaveState(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("BatchConfiguration.reader() ==> error " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return itemReader;    

    }
```

And lunch the job using CommandLineRunner

```
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataTransferJob")
    Job dataJob;

    JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
    paramsBuilder.addString("date", LocalDateTime.now().toString());

    JobExecution jobExecution=jobLauncher.run(dataJob, paramsBuilder.toJobParameters());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring Batch, a job instance is identified by the (identifying) job parameters. Please check the [The domain language of Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/domain.html#job) section to understand the difference between the `Job`, `JobInstance` and `JobExecution` concepts and how parameters are used to identify job instances.

> I tried to stop the batch middle of process and run again. It always executing a new job.

In your case, since your are adding the current time as a job parameter on each run here:

```
JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
paramsBuilder.addString("date", LocalDateTime.now().toString());
```

you end up with a different job instance each time. If you want to start the same job instance again, you need to pass the same timestamp of the first attempt as a job parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed parameter to Date only removed time part. Its working. Seems If I manually stop from sts it don't update the meta data.